# Squeaking oven door on my gas cooker

Tags: oven

I just purchased a new Lofra gas cooker with a gas oven and internal electric grill. The oven door is squeaking on my gas cooker.

Comment: Hey Dan, Welcome to the site.  It appears you submitted this before you completed your thought as I can find no question here.  Please check out the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what we do here and how everything works.  You can [edit your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/160110/edit) with more details and thoughts.

Comment: have you tried WD40?

Comment: A bolt or nut or hinge too tight, too loose.....